# does JavaFx Webview shares cookies with native OS Browser windows platform

Tags: cookies, iwebbrowser2, javafx-webengine

I want to ask a question that does JavaFX webview shares authentication cookies(persistent cookies that are created by the IE/Default browser)?

The reason why I am asking this question is I have an application that is using IWebbrowser2 control and this shares the HTTP only persistent cookies with default OS browser it means if application is authenticated once then the other application using iWebbrowsr2 does not requires authentication popup as authentication cookies is used automatically and access token is granted.

Now I want to develop the same mechanism using Java language. I have seen that webview in the JavaFx can be used a browser but It does not automatically picks the cookies and always shows the authentication pop up. How can I make webview to automatically accept cookies?

Comment: I suspect this is impossible, males sense right? Moreover, I can’t find much about it